# Under what condition I can "write" but cannot "read" from a location?

Tags: linux, embedded, embedded-linux, zynq

The purpose is to do DMA transfer betwee Processing System (PS) and  Programmable Logic (PL) for a ZYNQ 7000 board. I am trying to use Userspace Input Outut (UIO) framework. I have a UIO device in my ZYNQ board. I am using `mmap` to access the UIO device. From my application I can write to the device but cannot read, what can cause such behaviour?

I am given below only the lines that is relavant, ommiting all other lines. I am not sure the other lines are relavant or not. Other lines are unchanged. In the first case, the write command return `err=4` which is correct but in the second case, "read", nothing is returned?

```
fd_uio = open("/dev/uio0",O_RDWR);
mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd_uio, (off_t) 0);
err=write(fd_uio, (void *)&pending, sizeof(int));
```

```
fd_uio = open("/dev/uio0",O_RDWR);
mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd_uio, (off_t) 0);
err=read(fd_uio, (void *)&pending, sizeof(int))
```

The below is edited code in case we can use memcpy() instead of read?

```
fd_uio = open("/dev/uio0",O_RDWR);
fd_mem = open("/dev/mem",O_RDWR);
fromPtr=mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd_uio, (off_t) 0);
destPtr=mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd_mem, (off_t) 0);
memcpy( destPtr, fromPtr, size);
```

EDIT:

```
uint32_t Val       =89;
void *regs =   mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd_uio, (off_t) 0);
    *((volatile uint32_t *)(regs))=Val;
    uint32_t dma_status=*((volatile uint32_t *)(regs+4));

    printf("Value of errno: %d\n", errno);
    printf("dma_status %" PRIu32 "\n\r",dma_status);
```

In the above code I was expecting the dma_status to be 89 but I do not get 89. I get 0 if `(regs+4)` or I get 65563 if I do `regs`.

The following may help. I have tried to use reserve memory by adding the following lines in system-user.dtsi file:

```
    reserved-memory{
        #address-cells=<1>;
        #size-cells =<1>;
        ranges;
        dma_reserved:buffer@0{
            compatible="shared-dma-pool";
            no-map;
            reg=<0x30000000 0x1000000>;
        };
    };
    dma_proxy@0 {
        compatible ="xlnx,dma_proxy";
        dmas = <&axi_dma_0 1>;
        dma-names = "dma0";
        memory-region = <&dma_reserved>;
    };
```

But when I try to check if the reserved memory is there or not in the board, I get the following.

```
two:/home/petalinux# dmesg | grep eserve
OF: fdt: Reserved memory: failed to reserve memory for node 'buffer@0': base 0x00000005, size 0 MiB
OF: fdt: Reserved memory: failed to reserve memory for node 'buffer@0': base 0x00000000, size 512 MiB
cma: Reserved 16 MiB at 0x3f000000
Memory: 998020K/1048576K available (7168K kernel code, 243K rwdata, 1904K rodata, 1024K init, 118K bss, 34172K reserved, 16384K cma-reserved, 245760K highmem)
hw-breakpoint: found 5 (+1 reserved) breakpoint and 1 watchpoint registers.
```

Further edit:

The problem may be that when I type `dmesg | grep eserve`  I get
 `0F: fdt: Reserved memory: failed to reserve memory for node 'buffer@0': base 0x00000005, size 0 Mib`
and

`0F: fdt: Reserved memory: failed to reserve memory for node 'buffer@0: base 0x00000000, size 512 Mib` and

`cma:Reserved 16 MiB at 0x3f000000`
The output of  `cat /proc/iomem` is below

```
three:~$ sudo cat /proc/iomem                                                                                       
00000000-2fffffff : System RAM
  00008000-00afffff : Kernel code
  00c00000-00c5c727 : Kernel data
31000000-3fffffff : System RAM
e0001000-e0001fff : xuartps
e000a000-e000afff : e000a000.gpio gpio@e000a000
e000b000-e000bfff : e000b000.ethernet ethernet@e000b000
e000d000-e000dfff : e000d000.spi spi@e000d000
e0100000-e0100fff : e0100000.mmc mmc@e0100000
f8003000-f8003fff : dma-controller@f8003000
  f8003000-f8003fff : f8003000.dma-controller dma-controller@f8003000
f8005000-f8005fff : f8005000.watchdog watchdog@f8005000
f8007000-f80070ff : f8007000.devcfg devcfg@f8007000
f8007100-f800711f : f8007100.adc adc@f8007100
f8801000-f8801fff : etb@f8801000
f8803000-f8803fff : tpiu@f8803000
f8804000-f8804fff : funnel@f8804000
f889c000-f889cfff : ptm@f889c000
f889d000-f889dfff : ptm@f889d000
fffc0000-fffcffff : fffc0000.sram sram@fffc0000
```

Comment: `mmap()` returns a pointer to some memory you can read from and write to. You wouldn't generally call `read()` or `write()` on the file descriptor. You'd just access the memory.

Comment: @pmacfarlane  How to read from the uio0 without the read, may I ask?

Comment: I don't know anything about `uio`. But you'd generally either open a file and read/write it, or you could `mmap()` it. If the latter, you have a pointer. So you could, for example, `memcpy()` something to that pointer. Or from it. But then you'd need some way to synchronise the reader and writer.

Comment: I've added the `zynq` tag but there aren't many people watching that. Things like "PS" and "PL" mean nothing to most people. Or even "UIO". Maybe [edit] you question so it can be understood better by people who don't have this system.

Comment: @pmacfarlane Do you mean I should do ```void *memcpy(void *destPtr, const void * fromPtr, size)``` I just added the meaning of the varibale in the question.

Comment: Why are you using `mmap()` at all?

Comment: The UIO needs actual memory for data transfer. I want to do DMA transfer between PS and PL under UIO framework. I am working in this problem for the last two months and asked many questions in this forum recently.

Comment: I don't know that there is a user-space way to perform DMA in Linux, even with `mmap()`. I think you might be trying to do the impossible, or not asking the right question.

Comment: @pmacfarlane In the link it says that there is UIO framework but that comment is inside the slides so hard to locate. But there are many have done it, I guess as there are many many questions in the forum. https://support.xilinx.com/s/question/0D52E00006iI3fFSAS/axidma-driver-using-uio?language=en_US

Comment: Why don't you familiarize yourself with the basics - how `open`, `read`, `write`, and `mmap` work on regular posix files or shared memory - before you try to do advanced driver-specific UIO stuff on an FPGA?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I am doing it simultaneously as there is no option. But do you have an idea when ```write``` function works and ```read``` does not?

Comment: `read` and `write` are just system calls that invoke driver-specific functions in the associated kernel driver. While their semantics are generally defined, the specific behavior is completely dependent on the driver (and in this case possibly the hardware too). It's possible you're accessing a write-only hardware register or something but I have no idea.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Thank you for your reply. I am still trying to understand it. Is it possible that to ```read``` we need an interrupt and to ```write``` we don't? Or it has nothing to do with interrupts? I still don't the  problem I am dealing with; it is  related to interrupts or memory allocation.

Comment: For a `uio` device `read` and `write` system calls are used to manage the interrupt. To access the device's registers you call `mmap` which will map the registers into user space so your code can access them. To recap: in the device tree you specified the physical address of the registers using the `reg` property, the registers now need to to mapped into the user's virtual address space: `void *regs = mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd_uio, (off_t) 0);`. They can then be accessed as any normal memory mapped register: `uint32_t dma_status = *(volatile uint32_t*)(regs + 4)`.

Comment: @StuartMenefy Thank you for your comment. I have edited the question with an added information. I am really not sure why I do not get 89 but 65563 or 65562 depending on the value of ```regs+4``` or ```regs``` I use in the function argument. Can you help please? ```read``` will not work.

Comment: Not sure which DMA controller you're using, but if we use the [AXI DMA  v7.1 LogiCORE](https://docs.xilinx.com/r/en-US/pg021_axi_dma) as an example, offset 0 is the DMA control register, offset 4 is the the DMA status register. 89 = `1011001` in binary, 65563 = `10000000000011011`. For the control register, the bits which changed: bit 16 is 1 (IRQThreshold which has a minimum value of 1), bit 6 is 0 (marked reserved and always reads as 0) and bit 1 is 1 (marked reserved and always reads as 1). These are hardware registers, its not surprising you write one value and read another.

Comment: @StuartMenefy Thank you for your message. Yes I am using the AXI  DMA core you mentioned. I am understanding more now. It seems my ```mmap``` is working but not the interrupt as it hangs on ```read```. Really not sure how to find the reason why interrupt is not working.

Comment: The interrupt will only be raised after the DMA controller has completed the transfer (or there is an error). So your code needs create the scatter/gather descriptors in memory, set the `CURDESC` and `TAILDESC` registers to point to the start and end of the descriptor chain (hint: remember the DMA controller uses physical not virtual addresses) before setting the `DMACR` control register to start the transfer. Once all that is correct, the DMA transfer will occur, and the interrupt should be raised.

Comment: @StuartMenefy Thank you for your hint. I will try to use it tomorrow. By the way I am not trying scatter/gather mode though, simple transfer.

Comment: @StuartMenefy I am sorry to ask, but do I need to use ```CURDESC``` and ```TAILDESC``` fron non scatter/gather mode?

Comment: It looks to me as if scatter/gather mode is optional, a choice you make when you generate your design. So if you are using the direct register mode then you put the physical address in the `SA` and `SA_MSB` registers and the length in `LENGTH` instead, before writing to `DMACR`.

Comment: @StuartMenefy, I have edited the question further. Still not sure where the problem may be.

Comment: The `reg` property for your `reserved-memory` looks wrong. `reg` is a list of `address size` pairs. As each cell is 32 bits, on a 32 bit system you need one cell each for `address` and `size`, on a 64 bit system two cells. So your `reg` value would be reasonable for a 64 bit system (it would be 512MB at 0x5_0000_0000) but looks wrong for a 32 bit system (two regions: 0 bytes at 0x5 and 512MB at 0x0 - which is what you see in the error messages). So try something like `reg = <0x20000000 0x10000000>` which is 256MB at 0x2000_0000 - adjust for where RAM is on your system and what memory you need.

Comment: @StuartMenefy  ``` dmesg |grep eserve ``` tells me that ```Reserved memory: created DMA memory pool at 0x30000000, size 256 MiB
OF: reserved mem: initialized node buffer@0, compatible id shared-dma-pool
cma: Reserved 16 MiB at 0x2f000000
Memory: 735864K/1048576K available (7168K kernel code, 248K rwdata, 1940K rodata, 1024K init, 120K bss, 296328K res)
hw-breakpoint: found 5 (+1 reserved) breakpoint and 1 watchpoint registers.``` But How can I access that memory?

Comment: @StuartMenefy Please bear with me.  I am assuming this problem is related to the fact that I can write to S2MM_DMACR but cannot write to S2MM_DA or S2MM_LENGTH registers.  But are these problem related or not?