# Why I cannot write to registers of my zynq board?

Tags: embedded, embedded-linux, zynq

I have a zynq board running with petalinux. The .xsa file is to transfer data between processing system (PS) and programmable logic (PL) using AXI DMA. I am writing an application in VITIS to verify. In my application I need to write appropriate values to the regsiters for example S2MM_DMACR,S2MM_DMASR, S2MM_DA,S2MM_LENGTH etc. I can write to S2MM_DMACR but I cannot write to S2MM_DA or S2MM_LENGTH for example. I have functions to set the value of the registers and get the value of the registers. I can verify by printing the value after setting the register value. I can clearly see that I can set any value to S2MM_DMACR but cannot set any value to S2MM_DA and S2MM_LENGTH. I have used appropriate offset to access the registers. Any suggestion, how to fix it?

EDIT: I am accessing the registers through mmap and address in uio0.

I was expecting to print the value I have set the S2MM_DA and S2MM_LENGTH but it is always 0.

The FPGA design can be found in the link

https://www.fpgadeveloper.com/2014/08/using-the-axi-dma-in-vivado.html/

Comment: This reads like a summary rather than a proper post with details and code. Is this a continuation of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77582188/under-what-condition-i-can-write-but-cannot-read-from-a-location ?  "*I cannot write to ...*" -- That's unproven, and therefore a faulty conclusion. How do you know if the read is the operation that is nonfunctional?

Comment: @sawdust yes, it is related to that question.  I think read is not working as I am unable to write to the register S2MM_DA and S2MM_LENGTH. As I said. I can write to S2MM_DMACR . So I want to know when can I write to one register but not to another ? The code stops at read, so I assumed.

Comment: Make sure you have scatter/gather _disabled_ in Vivado, otherwise these registers won't exist. A quick look at the design you're copying suggests it has scatter/gather enabled.

Comment: @StuartMenefy Thank you so much. YES scatter/gather mode is enabled as sudo devmem 0x40400004 gives me 0x00010008 .. I never had the VIVADO design, I was given only the .xsa file to work on. I hade no way to fix this issue. I worked on it for 5 months....THANK YOU.

Comment: @StuartMenefy I got the VIVADO design. But the scatter/gather mode is "not enabled" so don't know why do I get 3rd bit of the status register MM2S_DMASR  1?

Comment: @StuartMenefy May I ask how did you find that scatter/gather mode is enabled? May be i am looking at the wrong place

Comment: @StuartMenefy You were correct. Scatter/gather mode was enebled in the earlier .xsa file. On my new (same design) I can write to S2MM_DA and S2MM_LENGTH.. but interrupt through uio is still not going though.

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to answer this question as it might help others someday. The scatter/gather mode was enabled in the Vivado design. It was not supposed to be enabled. Enabling scatter/gather mode does not allow one to write to those registers.